# Polylines with start and end of location in Google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have drawing polylines as the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
     var LineCordinates = new Array();
     for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     LineCordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].fields.latitude, data[i].fields.longitude);
         }
      linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: LineCordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      linePath.setMap(map);

    }
```

I want to place a `marker` at the start of the `polygon line` and `end` of the polygon line. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [documentation on google.maps.Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)
- [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

  ```
  var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:linepath.getPath().getAt(0), 
        map:map
      });
  var endMarker =  new google.maps.Marker({
        position:linepath.getPath().getAt(linepath.getPath().getLength()-1), 
        map:map
      });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you hold coordinates of polyline in `LineCordinates`, you can use its first and last elements as a reference for your markers:

```
...
linePath.setMap(map);

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: LineCordinates[0],
   map: map,
   title: "Start"
});

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: LineCordinates[ LineCordinates.length - 1 ],
   map: map,
   title: "End"
});
...
```